# OpenCV C++ Mat object dealloaction error

Tags: c++, opencv

The code runs but reports an error when returning from main().  I assume it has to do with the Mat object deallocation which is supposed to be automatic.  While working with openCV IplImage* I never had this problem.

**Here is full code:**

```
int main(){
Mat img_1 = imread("D:/cigare.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat img_2 = imread("D:/cigare1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

if (!img_1.data || !img_2.data)
{
    printf(" --(!) Error reading images \n"); return -1;
}

//-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
int minHessian = 400;

SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);

std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

detector.detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
detector.detect(img_2, keypoints_2);

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

extractor.compute(img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
extractor.compute(img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);

//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);

double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++)
{
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
    if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
}

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

//-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 2*min_dist,
//-- or a small arbitary value ( 0.02 ) in the event that min_dist is very
//-- small)
//-- PS.- radiusMatch can also be used here.
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++)
{
    if (matches[i].distance <= max(2 * min_dist, 0.02))
    {
        good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
    }
}

//-- Draw only "good" matches
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches(img_1, keypoints_1, img_2, keypoints_2,
    good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
    vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

//-- Show detected matches
cv::namedWindow("Good Matches",0);
imshow("Good Matches", img_matches);

for (int i = 0; i < (int)good_matches.size(); i++)
{
    printf("-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n", i, good_matches[i].queryIdx, good_matches[i].trainIdx);
}
waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

This is the error http://prntscr.com/c9cup8

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error means that you linked the wrong library version. Please be sure that you're not using debug libs in release mode, or viceversa, and that your libs are build with the same architecture (x86 vs x64) and same compiler as your project (which suould be vc14 in your case)

Comment: First librarys were made using vc12 compailer, so I made new using vc14 (x86) but error is still here. I'm using debug libs in debug (x86) mode. I didn't have this problem using openCV modules, problem started with openCV2 modules.

Comment: The problem ocurres in deallocation of vectors: keypoints_object, keypoints_scene,matches. If I first initialize vectors size to known large number that will fit i.e. <vector><DMatch> matches(5000) the problem is solved,but this is not practical and good solution.Any suggestions?